# How to quadruple an unsigned number using bit-wise and logic operator in C

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, unsigned

Goal:

```
4x ( 4.400000095 ) = 17.60000038
```

> - Legal ops: Any integer/unsigned operations incl. ||, &&. also if, while
> - Max ops: 30
> - Return bit-level equivalent of expression x + x + x + x for
> - floating point argument f.

My code:

```
unsigned 4x(unsigned uf) {
unsigned expn = (uf >> 23) & 0xFF;
unsigned sign = uf & 0x80000000;
unsigned frac = uf & 0x007FFFFF;
if (expn == 255 || (expn == 0 && frac == 0))  
    return uf;
if (expn) {
    expn << 2;
} else if (frac == 0x7FFFFF) {
    frac >> 2;
    expn << 2;
} else {
    frac <<= 2;
}

return (sign) | (expn << 23) | (frac);
```

}

As you can guess, my code does not work. Instead of quadrupling the input, the input is doubled. I don't know why since the fraction and exponent are   always being right / left shifted by 2 instead of 1. Im working with single precision floating point values in 32 bit machines.

Comment: Aside from sub-normals and near infinity, code only needs to increase the exponent by 2.

Comment: You cannot manipulate floating point numbers this way. Also, `4x` is not a legal function name.

Comment: both comments appreciated

Comment: You have 2 basic options. The first being a union containing an `unsigned` and `float` value which will allow you to avoid violating the spirit of *strict aliasing* by operating on the `unsigned` representation. The next being the technical violation by declaring a *pointer to unsigned* pointing at the float address. If you are allowed to use a union, that is the way to go.

Comment: Your title says you want `4 * x`; your example says you want 4.4 * 4 = 17.6, give or take some fractions; your commentary suggests you want `x * x * x * x` (aka `x ** 4`where `**` is a pseudo-exponentiation operator borrowed from Fortran).  Did you mean `x + x + x + x`?  Please be clear about what you want — contradictory information makes it hard to give a good answer.

Comment: good catch Jonathan... I cant use pointers. I will need to use unions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or 3rd option: Copy `float` to `unsigned` with `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes, or if the OP did not have the requirement to pass *floating point argument f*, a function that takes a `void *` argument which can then be cast/dereferenced as needed to extract/increment the existing exponent value, zero existing bits 24-31 and then replace with the new exponent value is about all that is required (along with a few sanity checks to insure the increment by 2 doesn't overflow the exponent byte, etc.).

Comment: Are you targetting a low-end CPU with no floating point support ? If not then  I would expect that using 2 x floating point add instructions will be much quicker than any bit twiddling solution that you can come up with.

Comment: What I got from the question was it was either for a homework to familiarize with IEEE-754 format, or for personal curiosity. I don't think the bitwise quadruple was a necessity for actually quadrupling the float.

Comment: It's homework for sure, but at least this poster seems to have made some effort, unlike the deadbeats that are the other two.

Comment: The code in this post is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276670/floating-point-multiplication-using-bit-manipulation, mod a,b,c has changed to expn, sign, frac.   I don't know who is copying from who, but it's plain that your class is abusing SO contributors since this question has now been posted four times, (including this one).   Im sorry if you were copied-from, rather than being a copier, but have a down and close vote anyway:(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a copy-and-paste of a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some untested code - leave that for OP.  (GTG)

The tricky bit is dealing with sub-normal numbers that when *4 become normal.  Also watch for large values that overflow to infinity.  If you want to ignore sub-normals, just `expn += 2` and check for overflow.

Another approach would `expn += 2` for normal numbers.  For sub-normals, shift the `frac <<= 2` and handle cases that become normal.

Code is about 30 ops.

```
#include <stdint.h>

float x4(float x) {
  // Use union to access the bits.  Leap-of-faith here (float is 32 bits, endian)
  union {
    float f;
    uint32_t u32;
  } u;
  u.f = x;
  uint32_t expn = (u.u32 >> 23) & 0xFF;
  uint32_t sign = u.u32 & 0x80000000;
  uint32_t frac = u.u32 & 0x007FFFFF;

  // Nan Inf
  if (expn == 255) return u.f;

  if (expn == 0) {
    expn++;  // Bring sub-normal into normal expo range
  } else {
    frac += 0x800000; // restore implied bit
  }

  // *4
  frac <<= 2;

  // normalize - this usually iterates twice, less for sub-normals
  while (frac > 0xFFFFFF) {
    expn++;
    frac >>= 1; // 1's will not be shifted out as 2 LSB are 0 so no later rounding
  }

  // overflow to inf
  if (expn >= 255) {
    expn = 255;
    frac = 0;
  } else if (frac & 0x800000) {
    frac ^= 0x800000; // clear implied bit
  } else {
    // still sub-normal
    expn--;  // should now be 0
  }

  u.u32 = sign | (expn << 23) | frac;
  return u.f;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that

```
expn << 2;
```

does not modify `expn`. You probably want

```
expn <<= 2;
```

Ditto for

```
frac >> 2;
expn << 2;
```

However, as @chux pointed out, you only need to increase add 2 to the exponent, not multiply the exponent by 4.