# floating point multiplication using bit manipulation

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to return the bit-level equivalent of an unsigned floating point number times 4.

So far I've been exploring other answers and found one that was pretty similar to mine, but also didn't work. There really wasn't an explanation given so I'm trying to understand what I am getting wrong when I run the test cases.

When I test my problems I get

> 33554432[0x2000000].

But I should be

> 25165824[0x1800000]

So far my code is

```
unsigned a = (uf >> 0x17) & 0xFF;
unsigned b = uf & 0x80000000;
unsigned c = uf & 0x007FFFFF;
if (a == 0xFF || (a == 0x0 && c == 0x0))  
    return uf;
if (a) {
    a <<= 0x2;
} else if (c == 0x7FFFFF) {
    c >>= 0x2;
    a <<= 0x2;
} else {
    c <<= 0x2;
}

return (a<<0x17|b|c);
```

Any advice?

Comment: That question has been asked few days ago already. You were told to use a fixed width type. Also you don't check for NaN, denormalised and other special encodings.

Comment: @Olaf I believe I check those in the first if statement

Comment: @DougCurrie I saw that question, but there was no solution in any of the answers or explanation of what was wrong with the code

Comment: "Any advice?" - Yes: `float uf4 = uf*4; return *(unsigned*)&uf4;`.

Comment: @barakmanos I cannot do that unfortunately. I am no allowed to use that type of solution solving

Comment: It breaks strict aliasing rule AND assumes `sizeof unsigned == sizeof float`, so I guess you shouldn't use it regardless of that... But you can still use it in order to test your code in a computer program rather than "by hand".

Comment: `unsigned floating point` - why didn't they tell me about that in school.

Comment: @4386427 my input is (unsigned x). Which means that it's just an unsigned number, so I have to isolate the sign, fraction, and exponent bits of the binary representation of that number. Then from there I need to basically perform operation equivalent to 4 * the floating point number

Comment: I don't understand your two sample values. You show decimal values and their hexadecimal equivalents. So what?

Comment: @WeatherVane I just included both for clarity sake. Sorry

Comment: Perhaps you are not asking the right question.

Comment: @WeatherVane How so? I'll try it again I'm given a 32 bit unsigned integer. That integer represents a floating point number with 1 sign bit 8 exponent bits, and the rest are the fraction bits. I have to use bit manipulation to change that number so that it is equivalent to taking a floating point number and multiplying it by 4.

Comment: Shouldn't you be **adding two** to the exponent `a`, not multiplying it by 4?

Comment: Doesn't matter about the poor defn. of the data type - unsigned/float etc. because this is the FOURTH post on this assignment.  What's more, you code is exactly the same as that posted by 'sam' except that a,b,c has changed frrom expn, sign, frac.   It seems like your entire class is hell-bent on getting SO to do your assignment for you.  I hope you all get an F-, you deserve no better.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are actually writing a software floating-point emulator (in which case you need more help than we can give you), you should let the compiler handle this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t multiply_by_4_as_float(uint32_t n)
{
    union {
        uint32_t u;
        float f;
    } conv;

    conv.u = n;
    conv.f *= 4;
    return conv.u;
}
```

(This use of unions has unspecified, but not undefined, behavior in C1999 with technical corrigienda applied, and in C2011.  In C1989 it was undefined, and in C++ it may still be undefined.)

(If you're asking this question because you need to do a little bit of floating-point math in a program that *can't* use the hardware floating point unit for some concrete reason, check your compiler's documentation - there may be an option you can set that makes it use its own software FP.  But keep in mind that software floating point is *orders of magnitude* slower than the hardware.)

Comment: For my assignment I am not allowed to do that type of conversion. Also I am confused as to what the union part is?

Comment: The union allows the same binary value to be used as two different data types. Two members are defined - but they are overlaid on the same data.

Comment: @ Unfortunately that is not allowed. Structures of that type are forbbiden in my assignement. I am just having trouble trying to figure out what if wrong with my code. I cannot seem to find any sort of help on this problem anywhere. Not on any other website or textbook or anywhere.

Comment: Well, if you are going to perform a floating point calculation by "bit manipulation" you will *have to* access the `float`'s binary data in some other way.

Comment: @JCD For clarity: if you're asking because of homework, then this is no good to you as an answer.  You are, in fact, needing to write an software floating point emulator, i.e. you need more help than we can give you.  Sorry.